# Getting error as ERROR TypeError: Argument not optional in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, polyfills

The below code works in all other browsers ,except IE11  in IE it throws the following error as "ERROR TypeError: Argument not optional" and the project is being developed in Angular 10

```
 private togglePageClass(mode: boolean) {
    if (mode) {
      document.getElementById('templateHolder')['classList'].add(...this.pageClass);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('templateHolder')['classList'].remove(...this.pageClass);
    }
  }
```

and the page class value is being set as follows

```
 let Mode: string = this.pageLayout['settings']['mode'].split('-')[1];
    if (this.pageLayout['template'] === 'landing_page') {
      this.pageClass = [this.pageLayout['settings']['id'], 'page-landing'];
    } else if (this.getConfig('configSettings')['100'] === 'on') {
      if (this.pageLayout['settings']['mode'] === 'abc') {
        this.pageClass = [this.pageLayout['settings']['id'], 'page-' + this.pageLayout['template'], Mode, 'a'];
      } else if (this.pageLayout['settings']['mode'] === 'xyz') {
        this.pageClass = [this.pageLayout['settings']['id'], 'page-' + this.pageLayout['template'], Mode, 'b'];
      } else {
        this.pageClass = [this.pageLayout['settings']['id'], 'page-' + this.pageLayout['template'], Mode];
      }
    } else {
      this.pageClass = [this.pageLayout['settings']['id'], 'page-' + this.pageLayout['template'], Mode];
    }
```

and I have made all the necessary changes in angular json and related files as per angular.io guidelines to enable running an app in ie 11

Comment: This is absolutely not how you are supposed to use Angular. `getElementById` ? `classList.remove` ?  Why include the Angular library and then not use it, and write some low-level Javascript instead?

Comment: @JeremyThille it is an code written by someone else ,handed to me to make it run on IE11 so complete rewrite wont be possible,even i understand its not the best practice when using angular

Comment: Well, I would rewrite it all in Angular :)

Comment: @JeremyThille not possible in short time span though ,any solution for the related question apart from rewrite

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, since this code is not at all how to use Angular and looks more like a hack than anything else :( Sorry

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I'm with @JeremyThille... a rewrite would likely be faster for me than figuring out some crazy hack.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the other community members for rewriting the proper code that can work for the IE browser. If we try to check the error message then this error may occur if there is an incorrect number of arguments or an omitted argument that is not optional. I suggest you try to debug those lines and see what parameters it pass when that specific line gets executed. It may help to know whether the correct parameters are passing or not. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue in IE11 for the md-checkbox in angular-material. I changed fixed the issue by doing the below change.
This is coming from **document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null)** this method and I added **false** as 4th param that is fixed my error.